# Can't seem to add put my token to market on Solana?

Tags: solana, cryptocurrency

I created a meme token recently as practice on dexlabs. I minted it but when I try to create market for it on raydium the transaction doesn't complete, yet it got processed. On oriontiols when I try to revoke freeze authority it says "token has no freezing rights" when I try to revoke mint authority the error message is "fixed supply".

I created the token on dexlabs and I might've mistyped something.

Linking the solscan metadata.

https://solscan.io/token/4mKvcj7VEXjCDGWJvx67nzzVA1LyyriHKzUknGzqzcov#metadata

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.